# can app in android depends on the type of smartphone?

Tags: android

i would like to know if the app depends on the type of smartphone, and not only on the andorid version that installed.

i mean if an app can be installed on Nexus 4 that running JB 4.2.2 and can't be instaslled on Samsung Galaxy 1 that running the same JB 4.2.2.

Comment: You can use filters on Google Play to deny a specific device

Comment: but why should i do that? there has a code that belong to a specifiec device and can not run on other device?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> i mean if an app can be installed on Nexus 4 that running JB 4.2.2 and can't be instaslled on Samsung Galaxy 1 that running the same JB 4.2.2.

your assumption that it's the "same JB 4.2.2" is not currect.
yes, it based on the same android 4.2.2 source code, but surely some things would be different in this versions, and not necasserly UI differences.

the true is that every device running entirely different OS that at least modified for the hardware binaries (drivers...) made it work in the specific hardware.

besides that, each vendoe adds it addiotions to the OS (like samsung touch Weis interface..), besides that - Samsung (for example) are actually modifying exciting components (such ListView) for their own purposes (such the bounds when scrolling top..)

and afterwords - you have usually more modifications when buying same device from mobile operators like AT&T..

that's before all the custom ROMS made by who know... (Samsung not provided official version of JB 4.2.2 to samsung galaxy s1)

I know for sure that all of this modifications **usually**  will lead to some crush or exception if your code is not generic enough.. (and sometimes just because the user runs your app on a shitty ROM that not implemented currectly...)

I installed also on my Samsung galaxy S1 custom JB 4.2 ROM, and tried to run Whatssap app (one of the best applications, also when it comes to stability and supporting all devices and OS versions)  and it just working bad!   crushing, not responding...
if Whatssap can handle this shitty custom ROMS - then I guess no one can..

> With a great power, comes great responsability

android is really great OS that running on thousands different devices, but if you want to make sure your app works great on each one of them (or at least the majority of them)  you'll have to to do QA tests on at least 10 different devices from different vendors / different build number/ screen size categories .

there are problems you can detect only like that.

Answer (score 0):

You could introduce flavors to your build. This is how to do it in Gradle http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Build-Variants

In flavors add specific variants of BuildConfig class which will keep references to alternative implementations

in build.gradle

```
android {
....

  productFlavors {
    flavorNexus {
        buildConfig "public final static MyAbstractClassFactory CLASS_FACTORY = new NexusFactory();"
    }

    flavorSamsung {
        buildConfig "public final static MyAbstractClassFactory CLASS_FACTORY = new SamsungFactory();"
    }
  }
}
```

then in code when you need specific implementation

```
BuildConfig.CLASS_FACTORY.getInstance();
```

where getInstance is the method which creates instance of whatever you need.